# Creating subfolders for organization in a zip file using Shell.Application

Tags: .net, powershell

I am writing a powershell script that will recuse through defined directories and copy applicable files into a defined zip file for archive based on the lastwritetime. After the files have been copied, the files that were copied are deleted to recover storage.

When copying the folders over, I am having issues keeping the ideal structure intact.  See below:

Folder Structure of files to zip:

```
T:\CodeTEST\TESTCodeZip\EnvironmentFolder\DatedFolder\files
```

Ideal structure within the zip file:

```
Zipfile\EnvironmentFolder\DatedFolder\files
```

From what I can see, the issue is around the `$zipPackage.copyHere()` as this will copy the files to the root of the zip file instead of organized by environment. If I pass $folder.FullName, it will copy the structure as needed but since i'm using the FullName, it will copy all files within the folder even if said files are outside the predication.

I am strictly looking for input on how I can get the ideal structure within the zip file as when I execute my script, it only copies the `DatedFolder\files` to the zipfile that are based on the predicate. This causes no reference to the environment the files were defined under which is a requirement.

Thanks for the input!

NOTE - All variables have not been modified to conform to verb-noun naming due to development and testing. Sorry if they are difficult to read.

I had an additional predicate which looked at the lastwritetime of the $folders (each environmental folder) variable but this was producing incorrect results as any change within the environment folder caused the lastwritetime to update and fall outside of the predicate where files contained within could still be aging as not all contained files had been modified on this property.

Removing the predicate and moving it within the foreach fixed this issue but has now presented the current issue.

```
Param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
    [string]$LogName='CodeRetention',
    [string]$PromotionDir,
    [string[]]$envFiles
)

Begin
{
    $scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
    $scriptdir = Split-Path $scriptpath
    $timestamp = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd-hhmmss

    $promotionDir = (Get-Content -path "$scriptdir\CustCodeDir.txt")[0];
    Start-Transcript "$promotionDir\logs\$timestamp.$LogName.log" -Force | Out-Null

    $getDateOffset = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-3);



    $envFiles = Get-Content -path "$scriptdir\CustCodeDir.txt" | where-object {$_.readcount -gt 1};

    $zipFilename = "$timestamp.CodeRetention.zip";
    $zipFilepath = "$promotionDir\Archive\";    #"# dummy comment to restore syntax highlighting in SO
    $zipFile = "$zipFilepath$zipFilename";

    #dot Source any functions needed for the script to run here

}

Process
{
    #Prepare zip file
    if(-not (test-path($zipFile)))
    {
        set-content $zipFile ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18));
        (dir $zipFile).IsReadOnly = $false;
    }

    $shellApplication = new-object -com shell.application;
    $zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipFile);

    $folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $promotionDir -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | where-Object {($_.Name -in $envFiles)};

    foreach ($folder in $folders)
    {        
        $delFldr = Get-ChildItem $folder.FullName | where-object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt $GetDateOffset)};

        foreach ($fldr in $delFldr)
        {                  
            "Adding $($fldr.Name) to zip file" | Out-Host 
            $ZipPackage.CopyHere($fldr.FullName)        

            #using this method, sometimes files can be 'skipped'
            #this 'while' loop checks each file is added before moving to the next
            while($zipPackage.Items().Item($fldr.name) -eq $null)
            {
                Start-sleep -seconds 1
            }

            "Deleting: $($fldr.FullName) `n`nFROM "+$folder.FullName | Out-Host;
            Remove-Item $fldr.FullName -recurse -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
        }

    }
}  

End
{
    Stop-Transcript | Out-Null
}
```

Expected: 
     Zip file contains the following structure:

```
Zipfile\EnvironmentFolder\DatedFolder\files
```

Actual:
     Current Folder Structure within Zipfile:

```
Zipfile\DatedFolder\files
```

Comment: Formatting seems to be bad:

Expected structure in ZIP:
Zipfile\EnvironmentFolder\DatedFolder\files 

Actual Structure in ZIP: 
Zipfile\DatedFolder\files